# Calling Kotlin code from Java Async

Tags: java, android, kotlin

[response](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ILNO0.png) [Test data get](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F0Kb5.png)

So Im trying to initialize some stuff I got with an Async function using Kotlin code. Basic gestalt
Kotlin handles some objects related to UI (a view pager and some other stuff including animations)
I get my data from an async callback in a java class
then on response I call a function which initialises all the Kotlin stuff with the java object.
Through the debugger it all passes through and the valeus are set, but nothing shows in the UI for some reason
Im sure im doing it right because, if I do the same thing outside of the async callback it works (with test data).
Is it something to do with Kotlin not supporting this type of operation?

Comment: Sorry, but your input is close to incomprehensible. A) don't talk about what your code is doing, consider providing real code (read  [mcve] and enhance your question accordingly) B) understand that other humans have to understand your question in order to help. So please spend the time required to enable understanding

Comment: You need to provide code that actually shows what you are trying to do

Comment: Sorry about that, am In complete chaos